# How does spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset works in spring-kafka

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

`KafkaProperties` java doc:

```
/**
  * What to do when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current offset
  * does not exist any more on the server.
  */
private String autoOffsetReset;
```

I have hello world appllication which contains `application.properties`

```
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=foo
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=latest
```

At this case `@KafkaListener` method is invoked for all entries. But expected result was that `@KafkaListener` method is invoked only for latest 3 options I send. I tried to use another option:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earlisest
```

But behaviour the same.

Can you explain this stuff?

### P.S.

code sample:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        this.template.send("spring_kafka_topic", "foo1");
        this.template.send("spring_kafka_topic", "foo2");
        this.template.send("spring_kafka_topic", "foo3");
        latch.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        logger.info("All received");
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "spring_kafka_topic")
    public void listen(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> cr) throws Exception {
        logger.info(cr.toString());
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

### Update:

Behaviour doesn't depends on
`spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset`

it is only depends on spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest

`spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit`

if I set `spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false` - I see all records.

if I set `spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=true` - I see only 3 last records.

Please clarify menaning of `spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset` property

Answer (score 2):

The `KafkaProperties` in Spring Boot does this:

```
public Map<String, Object> buildProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        if (this.autoCommitInterval != null) {
            properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG,
                    this.autoCommitInterval);
        }
        if (this.autoOffsetReset != null) {
            properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,
                    this.autoOffsetReset);
        }
```

This `buildProperties()` is used from the `buildConsumerProperties()` which, in turn in the:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(ConsumerFactory.class)
public ConsumerFactory<?, ?> kafkaConsumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Object, Object>(
            this.properties.buildConsumerProperties());
}
```

So, if you use your own `ConsumerFactory` bean definition be sure to reuse those `KafkaProperties`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-kafka-extra-props

**UPDATE**

OK. I see what's going on.

Try to add this property:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
```

This way we won't have async auto-commits based on some commit interval.

The logic in our application is based on the exit fact after the `latch.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`. When we get `3` expected records we exit. This way the async auto-commit from the consumer might not happen yet. So, the next time you run the application the consumer polls data from the uncommited offset.

When we turn off auto-commit, we have an `AckMode.BATCH`, which is performed synchronously and we have an ability to see really latest recodrs in the topic for this `foo` consumer group.

Comment: Artem, I just use method annotated with @KafkaListener

Comment: Good. Well, maybe you can share with us your simple Spring Boot application to play from our side?

Comment: Sure, added. It is example from doc

Comment: Is it because I start consumer and producer together?

Comment: Please, see an UPDATE in my answer

Comment: Spring Kafka does nothing with the `auto-offset-reset`. That's absolutely fully up to Apache Kafka to understand that property: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#newconsumerconfigs. I don't understand your behavior either. I told you: there is a race condition in our application when we exit after `latch` but auto-commit isn't performed yet. Everything rest doesn't make sense for me about `earliest`

Comment: Ok. at this case my question is the following: How to feel difference of different values of auto-offset-reset?  Can you provide exact steps? Description is not clear for me. *What to do when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current offset does not exist any more on the server (e.g. because that data has been deleted):* There are described only one example. Moreover I don't know how to delete data from Kafka